# Docker Node image not recognizing node_modules folder when it's available in image

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, next.js, yarnpkg

I have a Next.js application that I want to run using Docker compose

My `docker.compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.6"
services:
  ...

  next:
    container_name: next
    build:
      context: ./frontend/next
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/next:/frontend-app
      - ./frontend/next/package.json:/frontend-app/package.json
      - ./frontend/next/yarn.lock:/frontend-app/yarn.lock
```

and my `./frontend/next/Dockerfile.development` is:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node

RUN mkdir /frontend-app

WORKDIR /frontend-app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

When I run `docker-compose build` then `docker-compose up` I get this error:

```
next    | yarn run v1.22.10
next    | $ next dev
next    | /bin/sh: next: not found
next    | error Command failed with exit code 127.
next    | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

When running `docker-compose build` it's showing that yarn install is running correctly.
Even if I run shell into my image and do `ls /frontend-app` I get that `node_modules` are present.

What's am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
My `./frontend/next/.dockerignore` is

```
.next/
node_modules/
Dockerfile
```

Comment: You're using `volumes:` to hide everything in the image.  Delete that block from the `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending your node_modules to docker, which means it can't find the next bin. Remove node_modules and .next from .dockerignore

Answer (score 0):

**I got the same problem. And I found that when run "COPY . ." on dockerfile, it copy "package-lock.json" into container that make wrong.**

So after Copy all file into container, I remove "package-lock.json".

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV development
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./project .
RUN rm -rf package-lock.json
```

Here is my docker-compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./project:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "npm i && npm run dev"
```

it works.

*note: "./project" is source folder

tree folder:

```
./project
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
```